# FullCalendar - changeView Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar to display a Google Calendar. I want the calendar to change into an `agendaDay` [view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/). Currently, I'm using this block of code to change the view:

```
if (($(window).width() / $(window).height()) < 0.95) {
    console.log("Here");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', "agendaDay")
}
```

This is how my calendar is set up:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDIQZLuITK90tlTtdHN4cSkdLW9aRznnL4',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: 'db25n7oev1at726gljle5d784c@group.calendar.google.com'
            }
        });
    });
```

And, I am using Bootstrap, so I have this HTML:

```
  <div class="container first-container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="about-calendar">Calendar</h2>
      <hr>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am sure I'm missing something basic. I am new to web programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to listen to the `window` resize event for the outcome. You can use jQuery to listen like so. Other than that it looks OK.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey : 'AIzaSyDIQZLuITK90tlTtdHN4cSkdLW9aRznnL4',
        events : {
            googleCalendarId : 'db25n7oev1at726gljle5d784c@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        console.log(($(window).width() / $(window).height()));//can be removed
        if (($(window).width() / $(window).height()) < 0.95) {
            console.log("Here");
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', "agendaDay") //Change this accordingly
        } else {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', "agendaWeek") //Change this accordingly
        }
    });
 });
```

[.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

If this is not what you wanted, please let us know.